# Sorted data structure for in-order iteration, ordered push, and removal (N elements only from top)

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization, data-structures, stl

What is considered an optimal data structure for pushing something in order (so inserts at any position, able to find correct position), in-order iteration, and popping N elements off the top (so the N smallest elements, N determined by comparisons with threshold value)?  The push and pop need to be particularly fast (run every iteration of a loop), while the in-order full iteration of the data happens at a variable rate but likely an order of magnitude less often.  The data can't be purged by the full iteration, it needs to be unchanged.  Everything that is pushed will eventually be popped, but since a pop can remove multiple elements there can be more pushes than pops.  The scale of data in the structure at any one time could go up to hundreds or low thousands of elements.

I'm currently using a `std::deque` and binary search to insert elements in ascending order.  Profiling shows it taking up the majority of the time, so something has got to change.  `std::priority_queue` doesn't allow iteration, and hacks I've seen to do it won't iterate in order.  Even on a limited test (no full iteration!), the `std::set` class performed worse than my `std::deque` approach.

None of the classes I'm messing with seem to be built with this use case in mind.  I'm not averse to making my own class, if there's a data structure not to be found in STL or boost for some reason.

edit:

There's two major functions right now, `push` and `prune`.  `push` uses 65% of the time, `prune` uses 32%.  Most of the time used in `push` is due to insertion into the `deque` (64% out of 65%).  Only 1% comes from the binary search to find the position.

```
template<typename T, size_t Axes>
void Splitter<T, Axes>::SortedData::push(const Data& data) //65% of processing
{
 size_t index = find(data.values[(axis * 2) + 1]);

 this->data.insert(this->data.begin() + index, data); //64% of all processing happens here
}

template<typename T, size_t Axes>
void Splitter<T, Axes>::SortedData::prune(T value) //32% of processing
{
 auto top = data.begin(), end = data.end(), it = top;

 for (; it != end; ++it)
 {
  Data& data = *it;

  if (data.values[(axis * 2) + 1] > value) break;
 }

 data.erase(top, it);
}

template<typename T, size_t Axes>
size_t Splitter<T, Axes>::SortedData::find(T value)
{
 size_t start = 0;
 size_t end = this->data.size();

 if (!end) return 0;

 size_t diff;

 while (diff = (end - start) >> 1)
 {
  size_t mid = diff + start;

  if (this->data[mid].values[(axis * 2) + 1] <= value)
  {
   start = mid;
  }
  else
  {
   end = mid;
  }
 }

 return this->data[start].values[(axis * 2) + 1] <= value ? end : start;
}
```

Comment: *Profiling shows it taking up the majority of the time*. Which operation is taking more time? Could you post the code, so we can see what you're *actually* doing?

Comment: Wouldn't a map fullfill all requirements barring pushing/popping N elements at once?  And you could just do N 'pushes' or 'pops' (insert(), erase()) to get that.  Remember to use pre-inc on your iterators!  :-)

Comment: Don't you mean `set`?  Using the `set` with a barebones setup, so `insert` for the push, and `begin` plus `lower_bound` to get iterators plugged into an `erase` for pop, I got worse performance than with a `deque`.

Comment: If it's not key/value, I guess I do.  If it's a complex data type and you wrote it, you'll have written your own comparitor or operator()?  Try to make THAT faster?  And make sure it takes arguments by reference!  :-)

Comment: If you say "The data can't be purged by the full iteration", does that mean you cannot simply grab a copy and sort it, or sort it before you iterate? What if the data structure appears sorted whenever you query for it from the outside, but actually changes internally?

Comment: @ltjax As long as I can pop the N smallest elements (whatever N elements are < a given threshold value) and iterate in order, it doesn't matter how it is stored.  Of course, it still has to perform better than the silly `deque` approach.  What I meant by "not purged by iteration" was simply that I couldn't do a destructive iteration, like (for some crazy reason) repeatedly popping a `priority_queue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your requirements, a hybrid data-structure tailored to your needs will probably perform best. As others have said, continuous memory is very important, but I would not recommend keeping the array sorted at all times. I propose you use 3 buffers (1 `std::array` and 2 `std::vector`s):

- 1 (constant-size) Buffer for the "insertion heap". Needs to fit into the cache.
- 2 (variable-sized) Buffers (A+B) to maintain and update sorted arrays.

When you push an element, you add it to the insertion heap via `std::push_heap`. Since the insertion heap is constant size, it can overflow. When that happens, you `std::sort` it **backwards** and `std::merge` it with the already sorted-sequence buffer (A) into the third (B), resizing them as needed. That will be the new sorted buffer and the old one can be discarded, i.e. you swap A and B for the next bulk operation. When you need the sorted sequence for iteration, you do the same. When you remove elements, you compare the top element in the heap with the last element in the sorted sequence and remove that (which is why you sort it backwards, so that you can `pop_back` instead of `pop_front`).

For reference, this idea is loosely based on [sequence heaps](http://algo2.iti.kit.edu/sanders/papers/falenex.ps.gz).

Comment: Interesting.  I have some debugging and such to do, then I'll digest your idea and try to get a test working.  And thanks a lot, I was getting a little disheartened by "use a map!" suggestions.

Comment: YW, node-based containers are bad except for theoretical performance analysis :) However, note that the theoretical performance of this data structure will become very bad if the size of the insertion buffer becomes a lot smaller than that of the sorted sequence. With just a few thousand elements, you should be able to find constants where this does not happen tho.

Comment: Turns out this idea didn't perform better than that basic `deque` thing either, probably cause my object size is 16 bytes.  However, simply making my own really stripped down "vector" class that did *nothing* wasteful and sorting things greatest to least using `std::upper_bound` on insert allowed me to go from ~10000 microseconds per test to ~235.  This is no longer near the most time consuming portion of my code, so problem solved I guess.  Perhaps using non-STL containers with your algorithm (or at least no vectors!) could push things further.

Comment: Interesting, I wouldn't think that ``std::vector`` had any noticeable overhead over a plain array, unless you are compiling in debug. Which size did you use for the insertion buffer?

Comment: I tried many sizes on the insertion buffer, and got the best performance when it was larger than my dataset (lol).  So at about 4096 I stopped getting a speed up.  At that point it was ~3000 microseconds per test.  Anyway, here's why I didn't use vector, `erase` is "**Linear on the number of elements erased (destructions)** plus the number of elements after the last element deleted (moving)."  All I wanted was O(1) "count" to be decremented.  Maybe it gets optimized out by the compiler or something, I dunno.  I might try swapping in `vector` and checking speeds.

Comment: Well, yea - it has to call the dtor for each object, but if that's a no-op, it should be optimized out (for POD types, for example). Weird you didn't get any speedup for the bulk operations though. What was the lowest setting you tried? If you keep the vector sorted, DO NOT use upper bound to find the insertion point, just scan from the back, moving elements to the right as you go (like insertion sort). You are basically getting the search for free with the insertion anyways. upper bound just means an extra "random-access" pass on your data.

Comment: Damn, nice call on the insertion sort.  Went from ~200 microseconds to ~120.  For reference, finding the position first then shifting everything over with a single memmove (and inserting my value afterward) was also about ~200.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried messing around with std::vector? As weird as it may sound it could be actually pretty fast because it uses continuous memory. If I remember correctly Bjarne Stroustrup was talking about this at Going Native 2012 (http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/GoingNative-2012/Keynote-Bjarne-Stroustrup-Cpp11-Style but I'm not 100% sure that it's in this video).

Comment: Might well need the whole vector re-allocating in the event of an insert, and requires the OP to do their own sorting.

Comment: I've considered sorting in reverse with a `vector`.  The `deque` implementation in VC++ 11 appears to be simply data centered in a vector, though.  I'll probably get marginal gains from that, but with the hefty price for insertion remaining.

Comment: I'm not saying that's it's perfect solution, but if you know how many elements you could have in container you could allocate memory at the beginning. And by using binary_search to find right place in vector inserting would be pretty fast too. In my opinion most of time wasted in deque or map would be jumping around in memory. Of course using them would be easier, and intention would be clearer, but nonetheless vector could be faster (and it seems that speed is top priority here).
Edit: I haven't seen your reply 'user173342' ;]

Comment: If you don't want to write a `std::vector` based solution yourself, there are several sorted vector implementations.  `boost::flat_multiset` and I'm sure Loki provides something similar.

Answer (score 0):

You save time with the binary search, but the insertion in random positions of the deque is slow. I would suggest an std::map instead.

Comment: I have nothing to map to.  It would be a `set`.  I tested the performance and it is significantly worse.  And that's *without* full iteration, which the deque will obviously be better at.

Comment: You are right, it would be a set, not a map. Both are slower than a deque when inserting/removing at the ends of the sequence, but the deque is much slower when inserting/removing in the middle.

Comment: Oh, and just in case... did you remove the "find()" function when tested the set? (You should)

Comment: I changed the code to match the data structure.  Find would throw an error with a set, anyway.  My code with set was much simpler and used none of "my own" code (only `set`'s `insert`, `begin`, `lower_bound`, and `erase`).  Prune was accomplished with `erase(data.begin(), data.lower_bound(value))`

Comment: That's pretty strange, then. A search tree should save a lot of that 65% time that you are wasting on insertions. Maybe the problem of the set is the memory allocation of the nodes, one by one. In this case, a pool allocator might help.

Answer (score 0):

From your edit, it sounds like the delay is in copying - is it a complex object?  Can you heap allocate and store *pointers* in the structure so each entry is created once only; you'll need to provide a custom comparitor that takes pointers, as the objects operator<() wouldn't be called.  (The custom comparitor can simply call operator<())

EDIT:
Your own figures show it's the insertion that takes the time, not the 'sorting'.  While some of that insertion time is creating a copy of your object, some (possibly most) is creation of the internal structure that will hold your object - and I don't think that will change between list/map/set/queue etc.  IF you can predict the likely eventual/maximum size of your data set, and can write or find your own sorting algorithm, and the time is being lost in allocating objects, then vector might be the way to go.

Comment: Using pointers to perform all those comparisons would inevitably result in a slowdown (requires cache line for each object in the heap).  The object isn't very large, 16 bytes.